# Is Jxta still the best technology to build Java p2p applications?

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

All the documentation and articles I stumbled across are about 10-12 years old which makes me wonder if there's a better alternative now.

Comment: I can guaranteedly say NO. But, I don't know about the alternative. While thinking of building a p2p application, I was also looking for Juxtapose(JXTA), but, found it to be old for current era. Wait for an efficient reply...

Comment: What do you intend to build?

Comment: I plan to build a chat application possibly with chatrooms.